# Logitech Keyboard on Mac always uses secondary function key binding

Tags: mac, keyboard

I have a new Logitech MX Mechanical (Mac, compact) keyboard on my iMac 5K. I have repeatedly tried the "Use F1, F2, etc. keys as standard function keys" switch in both positions.  Using this keyboard I always get the secondary function (the one printed above the F#) independent of how the keyboard function key switch is set in SystemPreferences.  I can get the F# function if I hold down the "fn" key when pressing the F# key.

How do I get the function keys to work?  I have extensive bindings through F# keys in Emacs that I can't live without.

Comment: On my MacAlly keyboard, it's a magic invocation of keys to change the mode. It doesn't work via System Settings either. Perhaps yours is the same.